# Can I use APIs services from another backend server without api route default in Nextjs?

Tags: next.js

Nextjs already configured route "api" in my pages folder for handling APIs but i want to use endpoints APIs from another backend server address (ex: api.domain.com) instead of route "api" default of Nextjs. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The API folder inside `/pages` is here to create API endpoints as NodeJS serverless functions.
Nevertheless, it has **no** restrictive incident on your front-end.

You can call **any API** from your front-end if the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) allow it.

Comment: Can you give me example repo or demo code for authenticate (login/signin/logout) without serverless in nextjs ?

Comment: It's the same process as in ReactJS (NextJS just being a layer on top of ReactJS). Use a 'useEffect()' or 'react-hook-form' components to create the process for your form in NextJS. [Check out this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-react-applications)